# Performance Mysql Join or table with varchar

Tags: mysql, performance, join, varchar

If I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `codetransactions` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_customer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_cashier` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`program_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_codeaccount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`tmstmp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`value1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`value2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`comment` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I am struggling with the issue that with massive datamining  - this varchar field will massively slow down the operations.

My real question now is: is it better to split this table into two tables andextracting the "comment" field to another table? not every transaction will have a comment and with datamining the varchar will be irrelevant or is this just an illusion and mysql will take care of that?

Comment: Are you reading the comment for your data-mining operation? If not, you may create an index which does not involve comment. Mine on the fields in the index.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested - create an index to another table where you keep the comments. And also you are aware that the (11) you add to the int field doesn't actually do anything other then set the visibility?

Comment: hello, the int(11) is from my db editor which generates the sql code. But do you have any numbers, facts or just your oppinion to do it the separated way?

Answer (score 0):

- make another table say (**table2**) having columns -
      - **id**       - foreign key from your base table,
      -  **comment** - varchar(150)

so when ever any user comments then that user's id and comment will go to this table2
if you want to get the user comment then you only have to search for the existing key in table2.
so no need to insert empty row..

Comment: thx for your table, but i am just curious about the performance impact ... i know how to seperate two tables ;)

Comment: if out of 10 customers, only one user gives his comment(like in- near-to-worst case), so u can imagine 150*9 bytes of ur database just got wasted,so separation of table is only solution.also mysql is so efficient that it can handle  such small relations in fractions of seconds......even multiple joins it can handle very efficiently..